# how to have type dependent on additional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider I have names a object storing some object used as interface

```js
const items = [{name: "drop", value:"1"}, {name: "push", value:"2"}, {name: "increment", value:3}];
```

I also have the given interface

```
interface SpecialAbilities {
    bob: { drop(name: string): void };
    damian: { push(name: string): void};
    tubby: { increment(index: number): void};
}
```

I have `foo = (key, array)` which looks up keys by array.

I want `foo` to use foo in a way that it autocompletes the `key` argument:

```
foo<SpecialAbilities["bob"]>("drop",items) // autosuggests "drop" in vscode :)
```

```
foo<SpecialAbilities["bob"]>("increment",items) // TypeError
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Seems like a lot of typos in there.  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally others could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m3ypkw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Maybe you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOP7pN) but it really isn't clear; usually you don't want to make someone manually specify generic function type parameters, and presumably you want stronger typing than just "some key".  It's not obvious what your real use case is and it's hard to know how to advise further.

Comment: thanks @jcalz this is exactly what I was seeking for!

Comment: I could write up an answer but could you please fix the typos in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in order to preserve type information about the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` properties of the `items` elements, you need to change how it's declared.  Right now the `name` property is just `string`, and the compiler completely forgets about specific strings like `"drop"` and `"push"`:

```
const items = [{ name: "drop", value: "1" }, { name: "push", value: "2" }, { name: "increment", value: 3 }];
/* const items: ({
    name: string;
    value: string;
} | {
    name: string;
    value: number;
})[] */
```

A [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) is the easiest way to do this:

```
const items = [
    { name: "drop", value: "1" },
    { name: "push", value: "2" },
    { name: "increment", value: 3 }
] as const;
/* const items: readonly [{
    readonly name: "drop";
    readonly value: "1";
}, {
    readonly name: "push";
    readonly value: "2";
}, {
    readonly name: "increment";
    readonly value: 3;
}] */
```

That's better.

---

From your requirement that you want the following behavior:

```
foo<SpecialAbilities["bob"]>("drop", items) //autosuggests "drop" in vscode :) 
foo<SpecialAbilities["bob"]>("increment", items) //typeError
```

I suppose that you want `foo()` to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function, where the generic type parameter corresponds to some type whose property keys should be acceptable for the first function argument.  Everything else is not 100% clear to me, so I will just do the easiest thing from my perspective: the second function argument can be of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  Here's how it looks:

```
declare function foo<T>(name: keyof T, items: any): void;
```

Let's test it:

```
foo<SpecialAbilities["bob"]>("drop", items) // okay

foo<SpecialAbilities["bob"]>("increment", items) // error!
// ------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"increment"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"drop"'.

// foo<SpecialAbilities["tubby"]>( | );
//                                 ^--  "increment"
```

You get the behavior you asked for, including the IntelliSense suggestions.

---

So that answers the question as asked.  I'm a bit wary that you actually want to use it like this, though.  Seems like you probably want something more specific than `any` for the type of `items`.  But that's out of scope here, so I will leave it alone.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCIAcIwLwwNoG8ZgIYFsBTALhgCIATAJ0TIBoYA3XAGwFcTyBGMmAXwbY8RUmQRsIAC3pNWHUQCZeAmEIKcyASzDAqhImCgzm7TgGZ+AXQDcAWABQAegBUMUJFjwkpABSYHMIE46qTQVNoA5nb2QbKmoVDhYFEOfDAAPqoBQcKcYZHRsSbyOGz4AEaEVNF8AJToljDOjg4O7tAwmlD6yGjo2YFqIuTUtAzFGjz8dAOqwcNiEtLjchpK07NDGtq6+oSGxqukFnwOjbjI7VDRLm7gHV09pHq4FOAsAJ4Y-jFBL29gT7zDSjBBkQp-Qivd5fCaiHg1QSzf4w4GicRScHIqEAoFw8hKRFZX6BFGAr65UQ7PQGIwQ0k41H4sw1RrNVr2bTdKgAM1wwEIMAAyghCMBNKwAILlTQsLqaQjIH6xcogcqkbCgnyUmD5ZK1UiMECaCj8ekwCgECVgDUwDGSbUhXWJSIGpjG018c1QNjlcofW3UvaGHzaCiEAAepDAZUqVDdRpNZtSHPDwBYuD0MB5bB0UE04Gz8AAPAAVAB8juGAGtCB8QDyYKWGI98BBSLgwB8Ex7og4eSWRWKJSxpbL5Yr0GRVeUyJZK5QaGCW9027UYI5HHBq7gPhyByBi0PxVKZXL85Pp2q5wug7SZK2IOvNzAqjQqABCBwvgC0f--AGAUB-7ljAAB+EGQVBYHflukpUBEZT7J4jZQB8oowAA5FoOg0shZCYZ0yBgCAsAXBAmgRHg5QsIKUAgHambqNycCoehgrYaCBEAHQci+B5HqKJ6jmeE4QFOPp+h8N4+BkMC1DcW6xMpKmqWpgQAHp-jAgC8G4A5LvkHe+EckAA)